# ExtJS 4: Prevent auto-calculating of width

Tags: javascript, tabs, extjs4, width

I'm using `Ext.tab.Bar` inside grid panel's `tbar`.

My code is:

```
...
tbar: [
    ...
    "->",
    this._getTabbar()
]
// where this._getTabbar() is:
GridPanel.prototype._getTabbar = function() {
    return Ext.tab.Bar({
        width: 850,
        items: [
            {text: "Grid's Tab #1", closable: false},
            {text: "Grid's Tab #2", closable: false},
            {text: "Grid's Tab #3", closable: false},
            ...
            {text: "Grid's Tab #N", closable: false}
        ]
    });
}
```

As a result, I get correct top-toolbar, but buttons in the tabbar is too short and I can't see their labels. It means that tab-button *Grid's Tab #1* appears like *Grid's T...*

I've tried to manually add `width` parameter to the tab configuration:

```
{text: "Grid's Tab #N", ..., width: 150}
```

And nothing, ExtJS automaticaly calculates the same width for each button. I tried to set `flex: false` and again nothing.

What I want to ask you is what should I do to prevent flex-like width calculating? If I create 100500 buttons with "The button with long-long-long-long label", I want to see full text in all buttons in the tabbar.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a little confused. Grid panel tbar config is meant for a toolbar. The config for a tbar is typically:

```
tbar: [
  { xtype: 'button', text: 'Button 1' }
]
```

Toolbar is not limited to buttons. Here is an example of a very busy toolbar with all kinds of fields http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/PhAbR/embedded/result/

The tab bar on the other hand is for a tab panel. here is what the docs say:

> "TabBar is used internally by a TabPanel and typically should not need
>   to be created manually"

not that you couldn't :) So, are you trying to create a custom component with tabs? If so why not use the regular tab panel?

Comment: Ok, let me explain. The reason why I use tab-bar instead of buttons set (default for toolbars) is exactly tabs and tab-bar's native scrolling. My task is create grid separated by some property (tabs). So when user changes active tab, the data store will be reloaded with relevant data. If you know any solution how to add horizontal scrolling (like in tab-bar) for `Ext.container.ButtonGroup` I'll be very grateful to help. Thx.

Comment: have you tried to wrap your button set into a container with autoscroll ? I think the hbox is the layout that you need.

Comment: Tried and... nothing. `Ext.tab.Bar` has HBOX layout and docs for HBOX layout says that width of childrend will be automatically calculated depending to parent container width, to prevent this user should set `layout.flex` property to `0` or `undefined`. And this doesn't work too)) I temporary fixed current problem with `Ext.tab.Bar.minTabWidth` value, but still looking for solution.

Comment: Ok, how about actually using a Tab Panel and set each item as an instance of your grid. then add listeners on the tabs to filter the store a certain way each time (or load the store with different parameters for each tab). If you use xtype: myGridView your grid will be reused in each tab.

Comment: I accept your answer, 'cause there is no another ways to do what I want =) Just our comments helped me, thx

Comment: thanks!    hope you find another way to structure your UI. and don't forget: курение вредно для здоровья :)